# Generate a random number 10% of the time, otherwise generate 0

Tags: python, list, random, distribution

In Python I would like to create a distribution that picks a random number between 5 and 10, 10% of the time. The other 90% of the time, I would like it to pick zero.

I would like to sample 10,000 numbers.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and where you are stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `numpy.random.choice`:

```
import numpy as np

nums = list(range(5, 10+1))
# [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

out = np.random.choice([0]+nums, p=[.9]+[.1/len(nums)]*len(nums), size=10000).tolist()
```

distribution of values:

[image]

###### alternative

Other approach, if you want exactly 90% of 0 and the rest divided in exactly the same number of each value and the order needs to be random:

```
nums = list(range(5, 10+1))
out = nums*1000+[0]*9000

import random 
random.shuffle(out)
```